# May I use a CC BY-SA 4.0 image (own work) for an open access journal article under CC BY 4.0?

Tags: copyright, license

Some years ago I uploaded some images to Wikimedia commons and selected "own work". That images were uploaded under a CC BY-SA 4.0 License.

However, the journal (in which I am attempting to publish an article) uses a CC BY 4.0 license.

My question is, may I use this CC BY-SA 4.0 image in the CC BY 4.0 publication?

Here is the example of an article in another journal who did a similar thing.

Hsieh C-L, Yu C-C, Huang Y-L
and Chung K-F (2022) Mahonia vs.
Berberis Unloaded: Generic
Delimitation and Infrafamilial
Classification of Berberidaceae Based
on Plastid Phylogenomics.
Front. Plant Sci. 12:720171.
doi: 10.3389/fpls.2021.720171

[image: fpls paper]

[image: fpls statement]

Unfortunately my target journal has not a documentation or statement regarding use of creative commons image. I need to know the general or internationally accepted rules regarding such scenario.

**Update: The creative commons page
https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/ShareAlike_compatibility clearly states that**

> What does one-way or two-way compatibility mean?
>
> One-way compatibility means that you may adapt work under one license (X) and apply a second license (Y) to your own contributions, but you may not adapt work under the Y license and apply the X license to your contributions. For example, CC BY is one-way compatible with BY-SA. You may adapt a BY work and apply BY-SA to your contributions, but you may not adapt a BY-SA work and apply BY to your contributions.
>
> Two-way compatibility means that you may adapt work under one license (X) and apply a second license (Y), and vice versa.

This makes me really scared - like do i need to add a CC BY 4.0 license on those media files? and as @Ian's answer suggests, should I directly submit the image without a mention that these images were appeared on Wikimedia?

Comment: Your quote is intended to inform *other people* about their rights. You never gave up any of your own rights when you licensed *your* photos.

Comment: @Ian kindly make it clear that may I just withheld in the journal  that the image appeared in wikimedia commons. In case it is mandatory to mention, what is the proper format or language to write so?

Answer (score 1):

> Some years ago **I** uploaded some images to Wikimedia

I have bolded the most important word in this question. *You* own the images. *You* provided Wikimedia and the rest of the world a license to use *your* images provided they give you attribution and share alike.

However, you did not sign away your rights to those images.

From [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/):

> Every license helps creators — we call them licensors if they use our tools — **retain copyright** while allowing others to copy, distribute, and make some uses of their work — at least non-commercially. [Emphasis added]

They are yours to do whatever you want.

This includes releasing the images under **a more permissive license.** CC BY SA 4.0 requires that "adaptations must be shared under the same terms", or *shared alike*.

In contrast, the license required by the publisher, CC BY 4.0, does not require sharing alike, making it **less restrictive.**

[image: Schematic of relicensing]

You should reference the images to avoid any appearance of self-plagiarism.

Comment: Hmmm. misleading. The OP has actually already licensed those to you and to me through the commons. We can share and adapt them. Subsequent publication doesn't take those rights away from you and I.

Comment: Then a CC license means nothing at all. It would have to be individually granted to each entity. Yes, you hold copyright, but a CC license says you don't retain "all" rights afterwards. And wikimedia commons would be entirely worthless.

Comment: @Ian yes, you can relicense the work to anyone you want, but if I already have a license to use the image, the question author cannot revoke or modify the license after the fact (which is part of the CC license).

Comment: You seem to imply that you and I have no license at all since they were licensed "to Wikimedia". And that a publisher could enforce a more restive license.

Comment: Your mistake is that it isn't wikimedia or the publisher itself that wants to modify (etc) the image. It is that the public at large has that right and may want to enjoy it. The license is to the public at large. That is the essence of wikimedia and CC.

Comment: If I give a restrictive license to A and then a general CC permissive license, then A can also take advantage of the permissions. You can loosen, not tighten restrictions.

Comment: as Buffy's answer makes clear, you are most definitely within your legal rights to license your image to anyone you want, under any license, regardless which licenses you already gave out. But *the journal* may not be happy that your image is also available under a different license (which essentially makes the CC-BY license useless as long as you know about the other one).

Comment: You are confusing holding copyright with "retaining all rights". A license specifically gives away rights. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Actually CC licenses are "sticky". A derived work can't impose restrictions. It needs to be CC BY-SA 4.0 or more permissive still. Neither the journal nor the OP can take back rights already given.

Comment: Kindly see my update

Answer (score 0):

Generally, once you have given a permissive license to the public you can no longer restrict it. The publisher would need to know about the SA license that the work already carries.

My best guess is that you can use it and the publisher will agree. I doubt that they would reject a paper on that basis alone.

It might be a bit weird, however, if they don't actually say the image is CC BY-SA, but anyone else knowing the permissive terms can use the image without violating license. Your image seems to make it clear. Hopefully the publisher won't obfuscate it.

But you need to inform the publisher. They will work it out with you. But if you fail to inform them then there will be issues.

I'm going to guess here that the publisher will be happy enough since they are open access. The reason that they use CC-BY and not CC-BY-SA is that they want to let you retain rights to derivative works rather than, themselves, taking that retention right away through a more permissive license. But you've already done that.

Comment: Kindly see the update